# Replacing text in a file with the name of the file

Tags: python, csv, text, replace

basically I'm trying to write a piece of code that changes text withing a file to the name of the file itself. Basically I have a lot of files with `EMBOSS_001` as the first piece of text eg.`(EMBOSS_001|296133516|ref|YP_003640763.1|,33.06,248,157,7,1,243,1,244,7e-31, 121)`. I want to change this to the name of the file. I have file names ranging from `fp1_blast_output.csv` to `fp11000_blast_output.csv`. I want to change the `EMBOSS` part of the text within the file to the `fp()` part of the file. This is what I have, but unfortunately it isnt working!

```
from glob import glob

fasta_files = glob('*output.csv')
print(fasta_files)

for fname in fasta_files:
    with open(fname) as input1, open('modified/{}'.format(fname), 'w') as output:
        data = input1.read()
        data = data.replace('EMBOSS_001',fname.split('._blast_output.csv')[0])
        output.write(data)
```

Ultimatly what I want to end up with is:

```
fp()|296133516|ref|YP_003640763.1|,33.06,248,157,7,1,243,1,244,7e-31, 121
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: "I have a lot of files with EMBOSS_001 as the first piece of text eg.(fp()|296133516|ref|YP_003640763.1|,33.06,248,157,7,1,243,1,244,7e-31, 121)."
This text does not have EMBOSS_001 as the first piece of text?

Comment: Chris, as I have a large number of files I'm running it on a server using pubDB. It all seems to work fine until it comes to the output and the changes to the EMBOSS text isn't saved!

Comment: Enfenion, apologies, that was a typo!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
from glob import glob

fasta_files = glob('*output.csv')
print(fasta_files)

for fname in fasta_files:
    with open(fname) as input1, open('modified/{}'.format(fname), 'w') as output:
        data = input1.read()
        new_name = fname.split('_blast_output.csv')[0]
        changed_data = data.replace('EMBOSS_001',new_name)
        output.write(changed_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking,- and I hope this actually addresses your problem,- if you want to change some part of text within all .csv files to the names of those files (minus the '.csv' part), here's how I would approach it:

```
from glob import glob

fasta_files = glob('*.csv')

for fname in fasta_files:
    with open(fname, 'r') as finput:
        data = finput.read()

    data = data.replace('EMBOSS_001', fname[:-4])             

    with open('modified/{}'.format(), 'w') as output:            
        output.write(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your example input and expected/desired result is the same.
You can give the following a try:

```
with open(fname) as input1, open('modified/{}'.format(fname), 'w') as output:
    new_fname = fname.split('.aln_blast_output.csv')[0]
    for line_to_change in input1.readlines():
        output.write(line_to_change.replace('EMBOSS_001', new_fname))
```

and please also post your error.

Comment: Hi Pablo, thanks for the answer. Unfortunatly this script isn't working as fname isn't defined. As for my script the annoying this is I am running it all on the command like using pubDB, and it isn't giving me an error. As far as I can see it does what I want it to up until the output. The EMBOSS part is changed, but doesnt save in the output.

Comment: @BrianF I think you were supposed to exchange the "with open(fname) ..." line in your script, with the "with open(fname) ..." line in your script.

Comment: That is, to patch in the code so it matches up with your script.

Comment: @Enfenion unfortunatly still no luck. Same problem. The output isnt being actually written into the file for some reason

Comment: You know that you are writing the result to a file in the 'modified'-subdirectory, right?

Comment: @Enfenion I'm so sorry haha. I wrote this origionally a few months ago and the modified directory got lost in amongst all the files. Sorry for taking up yer time.